# Long site names shown in the visible communities in the Profile tab are not truncated, resulting in inconsistent left-column widths

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, whitespace

When users have accounts on sites with long names (for example, History of Science and Mathematics) and have them displayed in the visible communities list in the Profile tab, the width of the left column increases:

> [image]

An example from [someone else's](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/16591/michael) profile:

> [image]

Comparison for reference:

[image]

**Site names that cause the width of the left column to increase should be truncated so that the spacing is consistent whether a user has such site names displayed or not.**

Example of truncation:

> [image]

---

Note: This problem also occurs when a site with a long name appears in the "Hidden communities" section, but it will only look weird for users who can see that section of the user's profile (i.e. the user themself, as well as moderators of the site where the profile is being viewed). The column width will look normal to everyone else.

Comment: They are the exact same for me (Firefox 100.0.2, 1920x1200). Changing the browser window doesn't change this. Can you edit in your relevant specs?

Comment: @Joachim: Done.

Comment: No repro; Chrome (same version) on Win10.

Comment: @luuklag: Nope, no ad blockers. It's kinda weird how it happens only when I view my *own* profile, but not when I view someone else's profile.

Comment: @4168: Could you provide some screenshots?

Comment: Sure, here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTnRB.gif

Comment: Please demo the difference on *the same profile*, but between when you are logged in and when viewing it in an incognito/private tab/window (ideally the same profile when logged in as that user vs. when logged in as a different user using the same exact window width). The contents of the HTML for profile pages varies a *lot* depending on the user and the characteristics of their profile. Thus, any differences you see between different profiles can't be said to be because it's your own without testing *specifically* for that issue by looking at the *same* profile using two different accounts.

Comment: @Justin: In testing this myself, I tried looking at your profile and mine; the left column did appear wider when I viewed your profile than when I viewed mine. After Makyen's comment, I tried opening your profile in an incognito window as well – weirdly, the column width was normal when viewing your profile in the incognito tab, even though it was wider than normal when I was logged in. Then I compared against a few other users' profiles – and weirdly, the extra-wide left column is *only* happening on your profile.

Comment: @V2Blast: Wait! I figured it out! See this [user's profile](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/16591/michael). Apparently, long site names (such as History of Science and Mathematics) do not get shortened (`History of Science and ...`), so the column width increases as a result. Since you're a mod/staff, you can see my hidden communities list and notice that there 3 site names that are *very* long.

Comment: @Justin: Ah, good catch. I can confirm that even in incognito window, that user's profile has a wider left column – and it's for the reason you specify. (The problem doesn't appear to occur on most users' profiles unless one of those sites with longer names is one of their top 5 communities – since the list of non-hidden communities is truncated to the top 5, while the list of non-hidden communities isn't truncated at all.) Seems like there are multiple long site names that might cause such an issue.

Comment: @Justin: Anyway, thanks for helping figure this out! Mind editing your post to clarify/specify that exact issue? Then I can add the [status-review] tag, and we can escalate it to the relevant team internally. :)

Comment: @V2Blast: Done! Let me know if anything else needs to be added or feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue! This should be fixed now.